# Data missing from create view query in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this to create a view of a query in mySQL:

```
create view services_view as
SELECT `innovation_name`,`link`,`category`,`brief_description` FROM `innovation_db` 
WHERE `category`= "Service"
```

This ends up making a view with all the right columns, but there's no data. If I just run the query without the create view, it displays all the right data.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You need to create the view only one time and than you just call the view like regular table

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: View its way to define query one time and call to the view instead the table, you cant insert rows or update a view, its more suitable when you have query between multiple tables and you wont write the same huge query every time. view has an secure benefit that you separate between the view and the data.
-->  SELECT * FROM services_view <-- here you call to the view and not to the table, you get filtered "table" by category ="Service"

Comment: I get it. Here's the problem...when I call the view, I get nothing back. If I go to the view in myphpadmin, there are no rows. The columns are correctly defined, but there are no rows. If I run the query on the original database (innovation_db) without the create view, it runs fine and returns the correct data, so it's not as if there's something wrong with the WHERE part of the query.

Comment: Do you have row with category eq to "Service"?

Comment: Yes...more than 100. So, it's not a missing data problem. See my comment above.

Comment: If I do `create table` instead of `create view` it works fine and creates a table with the right columns and data in all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You then need to run

```
SELECT * FROM services_view
```

to retrieve data.

Comment: When I run this, I get nothing back. I should be able to look at the view I created in myphpadmin and see the data, correct? There are no rows in the view I create, but the columns are correctly created.

Comment: try to run `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW services_view AS ...` to ensure that the latest query is stored and then re-run `SELECT * FROM services_view`. Views do not store data, they just call the select-statement behind the view every time you request it.

Comment: This still didn't work. Here's what I don't get. I created another view using this: `create view WPPlugin
as
select brief_description, 
CONCAT('<a href="', link, '">', innovation_name, '</a>') 
FROM inno_db` If I then go to this view in myphpadmin, I can see all the rows with the full data. If I do the same for the query we're working on here, there's no data in any rows. What's happening?

Comment: Yes...the other view works fine. I can see the populated rows in myphpadmin and I can run the select and get the table data out.

Comment: If I leave out the WHERE, everything works fine like this. `create view services_view as
SELECT `innovation_name`,`link`,`category`,`brief_description` FROM `innovation_db` ` I can see the data and i can call the table fine. There must be something wrong with the WHERE statement, However, if I run the query in the innovation_db table in myphpadmin, it returns what I need.

Comment: Ok. Since it turned out that the problem is different than I expected at first and the select-statement works without using a View, I suggest using a subquery as a "workaround".

Comment: Subquery? Not familiar at all with that I'm afraid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62886/discussion-between-jonmrich-and-rogi1609).

Comment: what is the output if you run `SELECT category FROM innovation_db GROUPBY category` ?